# Script validacion de contraseña en formulario html [Servlet Java]

Tags: javascript, java, html, formularios, contraseña

estoy haciendo un trabajo sobre el juego del ajedrez en java combinado con servlets y una DB donde guardo la informacion correspondiente **el problema que tengo es a la hora de comprobar 2 campos de mi formulario html5 de registro de usuarios**, la script que tengo es bastante sencillita ya que he probado de otras maneras pero sigue sin funcionarme. La idea es que si un usuario introduce los contraseñas distintas por error salga un aviso de que las contraseñas no coinciden. Dejo todo el código java que tengo creado.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Registro extends HttpServlet { 
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
 throws IOException, ServletException
 {
 res.setContentType("text/html");
 PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

out.println("<html><head><meta name=viewport content=width=device-width,initial-scale=1><style>");

        out.println(".bg {background-image: url(registro.jpg);height: 100%; background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;}");
        out.println("input {width: 100%;padding: 12px;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;box-sizing: border-box;margin-top: 6px;margin-bottom: 16px;}");
        out.println("body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin:0;padding-top: 10;}");

        out.println("input[type=submit] {background-color: #4CAF50;color: white;}");

        out.println(".container {background-color: #f1f1f1;width: 50%;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;}");

    out.println("</style></head><body><style>margin-bottom: 0;</style>");


        out.println("<div class=bg>");
        out.println("<h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Registro</h2>");
        out.println("<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Creación de un nuevo usuario.</p>");

        out.println("<div class=container><form action=Registrado name=f1 method=post onsubmit=return valido()>");
        out.println("<label for=nickname><br><b>Nickname</b></br></label><input type=text id=nickname name=nickname required>");

        out.println("<label for=psw><br><b>Contraseña</b></br></label>");
        out.println("<input type=password id=psw name=psw pattern='(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}' title='Debe tener por lo menos un numero, una letra mayuscula, una minuscula y como minimo 8 caracteres.' required>");
        out.println("<label for=psw-repeat><br><b>Repite Contraseña</b></br></label>");
        out.println("<input type=password id=psw-repeat name=psw-repeat pattern='(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}' title='Debe tener por lo menos un numero, una letra mayuscula, una minuscula y como minimo 8 caracteres.' required>");
        out.println("<input type=submit value=Registrarse></form></div>");



            out.println("<script> function valido()");
            out.println("{ if(document.getElementById('psw').value != document.getElementById('psw-repeat').value)");
            out.println("{alert('Las contraseñas no coinciden.');"); 
            out.println("} } </script>");        

    out.println("</body></html>");

 out.close();
 }
}
```

El formulario se ve correctamente en el navegador y detecta perfectamente las condiciones de no dejar ningún campo en blanco, de tener mínimo 8 caracteres, una letra mayúscula, una minúscula y un numero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ACTUALIZADO**

```
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;

    public class Registro extends HttpServlet { 
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
     throws IOException, ServletException
     {
     res.setContentType("text/html");
     PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    out.println("<html><head><meta name=viewport content=width=device-width,initial-scale=1><style>");

out.println(".bg {background-image: url(registro.jpg); height: 100%; background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;}");
out.println("input {width: 100%;padding: 12px;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;box-sizing: border-box;margin-top: 6px;margin-bottom: 16px;}");
out.println("body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin:0;padding-top: 10;}");

out.println("input[type=submit] {background-color: #4CAF50;color: white;}");

out.println(".container {background-color: #f1f1f1;width: 50%;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;}");

out.println("</style></head><body><style stylemargin-bottom: 0;></style>");


    out.println("<div class=bg>");
        out.println("<h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Registro</h2>");
        out.println("<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Creación de un nuevo usuario.</p>");

        out.println("<div class=container><form action=Registrado name=f1 method=post onsubmit="return valido()">");
            out.println("<label for=nickname><br><b>Nickname</b></br></label><input type=text id=nickname name=nickname required>");

            out.println("<label for=psw><br><b>Contraseña</b></br></label>");
            out.println("<input type=password id=psw name=psw pattern='(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}' title='Debe tener por lo menos un numero, una letra mayuscula, una minuscula y como minimo 8 caracteres.' required>");
            out.println("<label for=psw-repeat><br><b>Repite Contraseña</b></br></label>
            out.println("<input type=password id=psw-repeat name=psw-repeat pattern='(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}' title='Debe tener por lo menos un numero, una letra mayuscula, una minuscula y como minimo 8 caracteres.' required>");
            out.println("<input type=submit value=Registrarse></form></div></div>");

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("<script> function valido()");
                out.println("{if(document.getElementById('psw').value != document.getElementById('psw-repeat').value)");
                out.println("{alert('Las contraseñas no coinciden.'); return false;} } </script>");
    out.println("</html>");

     out.close();
     }
    }
```

Te sugiero usar tu html fuera de tu servlet para hacerlo mas fácil de manipular

Comment: Eliminando "function valido()" sigue sin funcionar, a lo de usar html fuera del servlet no me han enseñado la verdad y he estado buscando la manera de hacerlo pero no lo tengo muy claro. Me podrias mas o menos indicar como hacerlo? Te estaria muy agradecido.

Comment: El inconveniente estaba en onsubmit="return valido()". Para poderlo usar con un html solo copia el contenido de tu servlet a un html sin el codigo java.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya esta todo solucionado. Pero para que java no de error he tenido que utilizar comillas simples, con lo que se ha quedado como onsubmit='return valido()'>". De todas formas de ahora en adelante haré tal y como has sugerido y usare el html fuera del servlet para ahorrar tiempo y complicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar de la siguiente manera:

Aquí el HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ejercicios</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center>Formulario</center></h1>
<hr>
<hr>
<form action="java.html">
NOMBRE: <input type="text" name="country_code" 
pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,}">
<P>EQUIPO: <input type="text" name="country_code" 
pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,}">
<P>APUESTA: <input type="number" name="country_code" 
pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}">
<P><input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Y aquí la función para desplegar el mensaje en JavaScript para comprobar que los datos están validados:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ejercicios</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var alumnos=0;
alumnos=prompt("Datos validados");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Es un ejemplo simple pero espero que pueda ayudarte a validar.